# Error:The "GenerateJavaStubs" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

after installing plugin.media library getting this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     The "GenerateJavaStubs" task failed unexpectedly. System.InvalidOperationException: There can be only one type with an [Application] attribute; found: ,at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.CreateApplicationElement(XElement manifest, String applicationClass, List`1 subclasses, List`1 selectedWhitelistAssemblies)at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.Merge(List`1 subclasses, List`1 selectedWhitelistAssemblies, String applicationClass, Boolean embed, String bundledWearApplicationName, IEnumerable`1 mergedManifestDocuments)at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Execute()at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() XamarinForms.QbChat.Android
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin depends on `https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin`

The Current Activity plugin adds an Application class to your Android project. Make sure there's only one Application class and attribute in your Android project.

Comment: happy coding :)@nitu

Answer (score 1):

Some plugins as plugin.media, DeviceInfo, CurrentActivity etc. are adding  MainApplication.cs that contains MainActivity winch conflict with MainActivity that is already there.

To resolve **delete** MainApplication.cs.

Answer (score 1):

check your project build output. Then you can find this System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

change it to shorth path Like C:\dev\project